# Can't start service, error 1053, made in Visual Studio, c#

Tags: c#, windows, service

So i've made a small service program, but it won't start.
It installs by itself, but I don't have it in auto-start.
It's on a windows 7, 64 bit system.

When I find it in Services, right click the service and have it start, it times out with the error 1053 after about 30 seconds.

I am running the program as release, and not debug. 
Tried to install as local admin and do everything as local admin.
The OnStart() and OnStop() methods are empty with no code, I removed it all to eliminate what it could be.
Tried putting a small logging action that I know works(I use it to create a log file when the install is successful) at the start of OnStart() but it never reaches it.

Help?

Edit:

Here is my Program.cs code:

```
namespace TestService
{
    static class Program
    {
        // The main entry point for the application.
        static void Main()
        {
            //Install self
            SelfInstaller.InstallMe();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Library.cs:

```
namespace TestService
{
    //Library to store public methods
    public static class Library
    {
        //Method to write to a logfile
        public static void WriteLogFile(string Message)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = null;
            try
            {
                sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logfile.txt", true);
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + Message.ToString());
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                //empty
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Service1.cs:

```
namespace TestService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {

        //Initialize
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //On service start
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
        }

        //On service stop
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your code ?

Comment: So even a blank service fails? that sounds odd.. can you show all your code?

Comment: Edited post. But yeah, it's empty.

Comment: Also tried to drop the self-installer and just to install with InstallUtil.exe, same thing but now it gives the error straight away, instead of after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you found a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21405/Windows-Services-Can-Install-Themselves) but followed only half of it.

Your current `main()` code will install the service every time you try to start it:

```
static void Main()
{
    //Install self
    SelfInstaller.InstallMe();
}
```

So that won't let the ServiceManager know the service has been started - as it isn't.

You need to decide, in `main()`, whether you want to start, install, uninstall or debug the service. It's common to do so using command-line arguments, where no arguments supplied means "start the service".

How to do this is also shown in that very tutorial.

Comment: Never worked with a service before, now i just feel stupid. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, there's a first time for everything. When learning about a new technology, it really helps to read the documentation to get yourself familiarized with the core principles, instead of following a tutorial that presents copy-pasteable code without much explanation.